# Facing problem in Deploying custom label using package.xml

Tags: deployment, package, customlabel, grant-login-access

I am facing a problem while deploying custom label through in package.xml using ANT.

I am using 

AGLI_SCH_Valid_Msg
CustomLabels

but error is coming up like entity is not found 'AGLI_SCH_Valid_Msg' I have double checked that this label exists
it is very urgent.

Comment: Facing same issue. Did you get answer for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I know its kind of late for the answer but if it helps anybody else in the same situation, it will be great.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customlabels.htm

Summarising. In case one wants to deploy the entire set of custom labels:
1. In the customLabels.label file we keep every custom label.
2. In tha package.xml we keep it as

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>MyPkg</fullName>
    <types>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <version>35.0</version>
</Package>
```

If we want to deploy particular custom labels(not ALL labels in the org). Then we have to:
1. Keep only those custom labels in the customLabel.label file.
2. The package.xml needs to be like the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>MyPkg</fullName>
    <types>
      <members>quoteManual</members>
      <members>quoteAuto</members>
      <name>CustomLabel</name>
    </types>
    <version>35.0</version>
</Package>
```

The main point to be noted is that, when we want to deploy all of the custom labels the component name in package.xml is "customLabels"
While in the scenari that particular labels need to be deployed, the component name in the package.xml is "CustomLabel".

Hope this helps.